# <div> stops scrolling using keyboard arrows when tabIndex is specified for the onKeyDown event to work in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There is one `div` that is always wider than the page have available space for it. It is placed in a container with `overflow-x: visible`, which in turn is placed in a flex container.

So, with this layout, if you click on this `div` and then press the left-right arrows on the keyboard, the container will scroll. This is the expected behavior.

Now I need to add an `onKeyDown` event handler to change the contents of the `div` when certain buttons on the keyboard are pressed (including left-right arrows). In order for the `onKeyDown` event to work, you need to add `tabIndex=0` for this block. But when I have the `tabIndex` added, the container stopped scrolling when the right-left arrows are pressed.

And this is not the expected behavior. I expect that scrolling the container with the left-right arrows from the keyboard will continue to work even if we started listening for keystroke events.

Probably, `event.preventDefault()` should be called to cancel this scrolling effect, but in this particular case I'm not calling this function.

Am I doing something wrong or maybe there is some bug in React?

Here is the code on CodeSandbox that demonstrates the problem:
https://codesandbox.io/s/onkeydown-arrow-scroll-problem-97e00l

**EDIT1**. Moreover, it looks like my "expected behavior" works in Chrome, Edge, but doesn't work in Firefox.